# Is there any good Tutorial or a Reference to cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

Cocos3d looks like a good 3d library to work with in IOS, but it stills in beta, and the
documentation provided on the [brenwill](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/) site is really not enough to 
understand how to work with it, it's just a guide about the classes no tutorial, and i have been searching the web for quit some time without any luck for even something close to a tutorial. Does anyone know from where i can learn this framework?

Comment: not really, cocos3d is not used by many, you're one of the pioneering few. the cocos2d forum might help

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the CC3DemoMashup project that comes with the framework when you download it. It demonstrates how to use many of the key features of cocos3d, and is well documented.